# Selecting and deselecting gameobject to change material

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting, gameobject

I am having some issues with my code.
I am trying to create a highlighting feature so a player can click on a game object and see what they have selected.

- I would like it to stay highlighted
  till they select another object.
- when they select another object the default material would be
  applied back to the previous gameobject. and it
  would continue for each object them
  select and deselect.

---

can anyone help me. I've tried a few things but it just keeps the color the same.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SelectionManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string selectableTag = "Selectable";
    [SerializeField] private Material highlightMaterial;

    private Material originalMaterial;

    private GameObject selected;
    private GameObject oldSelected;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Renderer selectionRenderer;

        //change the color to the highlight
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            //if selected set to highlight color
            var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 300.0f))
            {
                selected = hit.transform.gameObject;
                Debug.Log("1111 new Selection --> " + selected);

                if (selected.CompareTag(selectableTag))
                {
                    if(selected != oldSelected || oldSelected == null)
                    {
                        //save the original material
                        selectionRenderer = selected.GetComponent<Renderer>();
                        originalMaterial = selectionRenderer.material;
                        selectionRenderer.material = highlightMaterial;

                        
                        Debug.Log("Old Selection --> " + oldSelected);
                        Debug.Log("new Selection --> " + selected);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        oldSelected = selected;
                        Debug.Log("you have selected a new building");
                        oldSelected.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial = originalMaterial;
                    }

                    //comment 2

                }

            }
            //comment 3

        }


        //comment1

    }


    void ClearSelection()
    {
        if (selected == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            selected.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial = originalMaterial;
            selected = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is basically that you are not assign `oldSelected` correctly.

Fixing this, your code should look like:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SelectionManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string selectableTag = "Selectable";
    [SerializeField] private Material highlightMaterial;

    private Material originalMaterial;

    private GameObject selected = null;
    private GameObject oldSelected = null;

    private Renderer selectionRenderer;
    private Renderer oldSelectionRenderer;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //change the color to the highlight
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            //if selected set to highlight color
            var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 300.0f))
            {
                selected = hit.transform.gameObject;
                Debug.Log("1111 new Selection --> " + selected);

                if (selected.CompareTag(selectableTag))
                {
                    //newSelection
                    if(selected != oldSelected)
                    {
                        //Set original material to oldSelected if it's not the first selection
                        if(oldSelected != null)
                        {
                            oldSelectionRenderer = oldSelected.GetComponent<Renderer>();
                            oldSelectionRenderer.material = originalMaterial;
                        }

                        //Set highlighted material to selected
                        selectionRenderer = selected.GetComponent<Renderer>();                        
                        originalMaterial = selectionRenderer.material;                        
                        selectionRenderer.material = highlightMaterial;

                        //assign oldSelected GO to your current selection
                        oldSelected = selected;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```